# What is the meaning of the phrase "Signal Advance?"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage, science

I posted this question, [“Signal Advance”: Unsure of meaning or contextual use](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/41505/16651), on Biology SE, as the phrase was used in a biology text that I am reading, *Recombinant DNA; Genes and Genomes - A Short Course - Third Edition* by James D. Watson, et. al. I came across this paragraph in the discussion about discrete factors of inheritance in Mendelian genetics:

> The character shown by a plant depends on the pair of factors it receives from its parents. If both factors it receives are the same, that is, two dominant (yellow seed) or two recessive (green seed), then the plant exhibits those traits - yellow seeds for the former and green seeds for the latter. If one factor is dominant and the other recessive, then the dominant character is expressed; in this case, a plant with a factor for yellow seed and one for green seed will show the dominant trait, yellow seed. But the factor for green seed persists, even if the plant is yellow, and can reappear unchanged in later generations. **This was a signal advance.** In the 19th century it was believed that the traits of parents were blended in their offspring and, once mixed, the contributing traits could not be recovered. At the time, this was a severe problem for Charles Darwin's theory of evolution through natural selection. His critics pointed to that any favorable variation arising in an individual would have no long-term effect, because it would immediately be lost by blending.

I had never come across the phrase *signal advance* before and wasn't sure of its meaning based on its context in this paragraph.

The context was difficult to ascertain, as the first part of the paragraph referred to a genetics concept, where **signal** could be a noun and **advance** could be a verb, but the second part of the paragraph discussed the hypothesis and how it provided evidence to change the thinking of the day.

However, after reading the question in the comments, I am beginning to think that **signal** was possibly being used as an adjective and **advance** was the noun that it modified.

I looked for the definition of **signal** when used as an adjective, and this definition may be applicable:

> unusual; notable; outstanding: *a signal exploit.*

If that is the case, then the sentence likely means *this was notable progress.*

I'd appreciate any feedback, especially if someone has come across this usage in scientific writing.

Comment: [**signal**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/signal) *unusual; notable; outstanding*. This is General Reference.

Comment: You are misreading this as attributive noun + noun, forming a compound, where the sense might be expected to be 'an advance pertaining to signals'. As FF says, it's adjective + noun: _a significant advance_.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. If you notice, further down in my post I do question whether the structure is instead adjective + noun.

Answer (score 0):

As FumbleFingers and Edwin Ashworth have noted in comments beneath the posted question, *signal*, when used as an adjective, carries the meaning "notable, outstanding, or significant." Here is the relevant definition in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010):

> **signal** ... *adj.* Notably out of the ordinary: *a signal feat*; *a signal event*.

Thus, in Cletus Daniel, [*Bitter Harvest, a History of California Farmworkers, 1870-1941*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LkSO4UjnPMUC&pg=PA262&dq=%22a+signal+advance%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifsOXW0Mv1AhV8D0QIHU-CA804ChDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20signal%20advance%22&f=false) (1982):

> And if the nationalist idealism that the [Franklin] Roosevelt administration embraced in 1933 was largely negated as organized farmers and workers successfully pursued the politics of self-interest, the changes in economic power relationships that their activism promoted represented a **signal advance** in the development of democratic pluralism in the United States.

and in "[Conviviality: Particular Religions, Universalist Fellowship—Sme Jewish Reflections](https://books.google.com/books?id=kb2aCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22a+signal+advance%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizyfWG0sv1AhV2KEQIHfzTBuQ4FBDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20signal%20advance%22&f=false)," in *Living Traditions and Universal Conviviality: Prospects and Challenges for Peace in Multireligious Communities* (2016):

> Progress, for most of human history, would simply have consisted of an end to recurrent killings, conquests, and persecution. For much of the world's people even today, a cessation of religiously inspired (or ideologically inspired) murder and degradation would still herald a **signal advance** for millions of suffering people. The Talmud already contains such a reinterpretation.

"signal advance" means approximately the same thing as "milestone" or "important step."

Muddying the waters slightly are some instances where "signal advance" functions as a noun phrase referring to some particular physical or engineering phenomenon. For example, from Steven Smith, [*Digital Signal Processing: A Practical Guide for Engineers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CdtQBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22a+signal+advance%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj30-ir0Mv1AhWgIkQIHfpdD50Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20signal%20advance%22&f=false) (2013):

> The impulse response in Fig. 7-1c is a delta function with a **shift**. This results in a system that introduces an identical shift between the input an output signals. This could be described as a signal **delay**, or a signal **advance**, depending on the direction of the shift. Letting the shift be represented by the parameter, *s*, this can be written as the equation:
>
> > *x*[*n*] * δ[*n* + *s*} = *x*[*n* + *s*]

From Jonas Gomes & ‎Luiz Velho, [*From Fourier Analysis to Wavelets*](https://books.google.com/books?id=N4qQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&dq=%22a+signal+advance%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99K612Mv1AhV6JUQIHYqUCXE4KBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20signal%20advance%22&f=false) (2015):

> ...we say that the filter bank has the property of *perfect reconstruction*. Usually, we have perfect reconstruction, but with a delay of the signal, which is not a problem because we can compensate that with a **signal advance** within the system.

And from "[Electronic Interruptor](https://books.google.com/books?id=eWwbAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA606&dq=%22a+signal+advance%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj30-ir0Mv1AhWgIkQIHfpdD50Q6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20signal%20advance%22&f=false)," in *Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office* (1964):

> A signal generator for providing signals which may be varied in time and duration comprising: a plurality of magnetic cores of substantially rectangular hysteresis loop material, each having a plurality of windings; signal generating means for applying a signal to a winding on at least one of said magnetic cores, said plurality of windings including a signal input, a **signal advance** and a signal output winding; coupling means individually connecting said **signal advance** winding on one of said magnetic cores with said signal input winding on a succeeding magnetic core, said coupling mans enabling said signal to be progressively advance through each of said magnetic cores in succession; ...

Outside the relatively narrow area of wave physics, however, a "signal advance" almost always refers to an advance that is noteworthy—not to a process for moving signals forward. That certainly appears to be the case with the instance from genetics that the poster asks about.